# Winsock chat server and client application

Tags: c++, windows, server, chat, client

I have made a C++ command line chat with server and clients as a hobby project.

Here is [the GitHub link](https://github.com/VedantParanjape/Chat-Server-and-Client).

```
#include <iostream>

#include <winsock2.h>

#include <windows.h>

#include "Class_Logger.hpp"

using namespace std;

SOCKET ServerCom = INVALID_SOCKET;

int ClientAddressSize;

SOCKADDR_IN ClientAddress;

 char lftxt[40] = "../Logs/ClientNetworkInitLogs";

 logfile lf(lftxt);

 class ClientNetworkInit

{

    private:

     WSAData ClientNetworkData;

 char message[512];

  public:

  ClientNetworkInit(char sIP[],u_short sPORT)

   {

    lf.writeLog(sIP);

   cout<<"Intializing Winsock API";

        strcpy(lftxt,"Initializing Winsock API");

        lf.writeLog(lftxt);



     for(int i=0;i<15;i++) 

     {

         cout<<".";

         Sleep(100);

     }

     if(!WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,1),(WSAData*)&ClientNetworkData))

     {

        cout<<"done"<<endl;

        strcpy(lftxt,"done");

         lf.writeLog(lftxt);

        }

        else

        {

            cout<<"Error starting Winsock API"<<endl;

            strcpy(lftxt,"Error starting Winsock API");

         lf.writeLog(lftxt);



         cout<<"Shutting down the server"<<endl;

         strcpy(lftxt,"Error starting Winsock API");

         lf.writeLog(lftxt);

            lf.~logfile();



            closesocket(ServerCom);

 WSACleanup();

 exit(0);

        }

   ClientAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(sIP);

     ClientAddress.sin_port = htons(sPORT);

     ClientAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;



     ClientAddressSize = sizeof(ClientAddress);

     ServerCom = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);



     if(ServerCom == INVALID_SOCKET)

     {

     cout<<"Error initialising socket"<<endl;

     strcpy(lftxt,"Error starting socket");

         lf.writeLog(lftxt);

         lf.~logfile();

            closesocket(ServerCom);

 WSACleanup();

 exit(0);

        }

        else

        {

            cout<<"Socket Intialised"<<endl;

            strcpy(lftxt,"Socket Intialised");

         lf.writeLog(lftxt);

        }

    }

 void ConnectServer()

 {

 int val;

 val = connect(ServerCom,     (SOCKADDR*)&ClientAddress,ClientAddressSize); 

 if(!val)

 {

    cout<<"Connected to server"<<endl;

     strcpy(lftxt,"Connected to server");

         lf.writeLog(lftxt);

        } 



     else

     {

     cout<<"Unable to connect to the server"<<endl; 

     strcpy(lftxt,"Unable to connect to the server");

         lf.writeLog(lftxt);



     cout<<"Closing chat client"<<endl;

     strcpy(lftxt,"Closing chat client");

         lf.writeLog(lftxt);

         lf.~logfile();



     WSACleanup();

     exit(0);

     }

 }

  };
```

I am a grade 12 student. The C++ syllabus doesn't even include vectors, but I still pulled this project off on my own. Please take this fact into consideration.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This is off-topic because "_Questions must include the code to be reviewed. Links to code hosted on third-party sites are permissible, but the most relevant excerpts must be embedded in the question itself._" see the section **Make sure you include your code in your question** on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Which site is appropriate for such a question? As i was kicked from SO and told to ask the question here

Comment: @SamOnela Can you still take a look at it? Please!!!!!

Comment: You can post it here - just paste the most relevant parts of your code - ensure you  indent with four spaces to create a pre-formatted code block (i.e. <pre><code>) - see more in [markdown help](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code).

Comment: @SamOnela done, is this appropriate?

Comment: Yeah I think it is now on-topic. Hopefully you receive useful answers!